# How to subscribe to a blog on Blogspot via email?

Tags: blogger

Subscribing to a blog is possible via RSS and/or Atom. But when I search for it on Google, the results show how to do this for the author. I mean how can an author of a blog provide a facility to allow subscribing via email?

I want to receive new posts by email.

Answer (score 3):

To enable Follow by Email, click the Add a Gadget link from the Design -> Page Elements tab, and then select the Follow by Email gadget which should be at the top of the list.

Once you add the gadget, readers visiting your blog can then just enter their email address and click Submit.

Comment: For blogger.com today, the procedure is:  sign in | select your blog | **Layout** | + Add a Gadget | Follow by Email

Answer (score 3):

Blogger has [stopped FollowByEmail service](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/10477563) in 2021 that was used to send emails to Blogspot email subscribers. Worry not. There are several other solutions:

1. You can opt for other 'RSS feed to email' services like https://blogtrottr.com/ or feedrabbit.com. I prefer blogtrottr as it's straight forward and doesn't force you to create an account like feedrabbit.
2. If you already have an account on Zapier or IFTTT (or any other workflow automation service), then they also have 'RSS feed to email' services.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a simple way to do this:

> 1. Sign in to Blogger.
> 2. In the left menu, click Reading list .
> 3. In the top right, click Edit .
> 4. Click Add.
> 5. Type the URL of the blog you want to follow.
> 6. Click Next.
> 7. Choose whether to follow publicly or anonymously.
> 8. Click Follow.

[source](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/99761)

Answer (score 1):

There are a handful of services that will monitor RSS feeds and send you email.

- https://feedmail.org: Paid, free trial, realtime updates, minimal templates.
- https://blogtrottr.com: Paid or ad supported, realtime updates, heavy templates.
- https://feedrabbit.com: Free forever within limits or paid, clean templates

For all of these services you can just paste in a blogger link and they will discover the feeds.